# Trying to know why is this code leading into an infinite loop

Tags: c

I have been trying to get the factorial of a number (f.ex: 4! = 24 [4 (3) (2) (1) = 24]).

And I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void TestAcomulador(int a, int factorizado, int *resultado);

int main(void) {
    int a, resultado, factorizado, sacaroperacion;
    printf("Introduzca un numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    TestAcomulador(a, factorizado, &resultado);
    printf("%d", resultado);
}

void TestAcomulador(int a, int numprincipal, int *factorizado) {
    numprincipal = --a;
    do {
        *factorizado = numprincipal * a;
        printf("The loop is here\n"); //LOOP IN THIS LINE
    } while (numprincipal > 0);
}
```

What is going on and what I'm doing wrong? help would be appreciated to avoid getting this problems in the future,

thanks in advance.

Comment: `numprincipal` is not changing in the loop. So why would it terminate?

Comment: `while(numprincipal > 0);` is your conditional, and that variable doesn't change in the loop

Comment: What problem. You do understand that *you* have to tell *us* what's happening to get it diagnosed, right?

Comment: One thing that would help some is indenting your code properly

Comment: @EugeneSh. why is not changing if i'm doing `numprincipal = --a;` ? `a` is the number inputted by the user, and now i'm subtracting 1 from it till it's 1, when it reaches 0, it will stop and make the operation.

Comment: Because it is outside the loop.

Comment: Indenting your code could prove to be a tool for finding, avoiding and understanding this kind of problem.

Comment: Put it inside the `do{ ... }while()` loop.

Comment: @KamilCuk That would influence the value of `a`, probably undesired. Solution must be slightly more complex.

Comment: It is desired, OP said above that the loop should run until `a` reaches 0.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't decrementing numprincipal at any point, so it'll always be greater than 0 (assuming you a>=2).

So the while loop's condition is always true.

Comment: how can i actually decrement it then?

Comment: What is your favorite way of decreasing the value of a variable by 1?